# Permissions error installing new theme in Concrete5

Tags: apache, permissions, file-permissions, concrete5

I've just installed Concrete 5 CMS by following the instructions on the [website](http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.7/installation/installation/).

> The folders application/files/, application/config/, packages/ and
>   updates/ will need to be writable by the web server process. This can
>   mean that the folders will need to be "world writable", depending on
>   your hosting environment. If your server supports running as
>   suexec/phpsuexec, the files should be owned by your user account, and
>   set as 755 on all of them. That means that your web server process can
>   do anything it likes to them, but nothing else can (although everyone
>   can view them, which is expected.) If this isn't possible, another
>   good option is to set the apache user (either "apache" or "nobody") as
>   having full rights to these file. If neither are possible, chmod 777
>   to files/ and all items within (e.g. chmod -R 777 file/*)

The packages folder has permission 777 and root/tmp folder has permission 755.

I've uploaded a new theme to /packages over FTP. When I try to install the new theme I see the following error:

> An unexpected error occurred. fopen(/root/tmp/1419851019.zip) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied

I have FTP access to the server and access to CPanel. How do I get this working without granting too many permissions which pose a security risk?

Comment: Are you trying to add your own custom theme or one from the market place?

Answer (score 0):

My install has the folders **application/files, application/config, packages, and updates** all set to **755** and it's working just fine.

Comment: I've set all of these folders to 777 (temporarily) and it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because the system is trying to write to /root/tmp, which apparently is the environment configuration for a temp folder when your PHP request is handled.

Try adding the folder **application/files/tmp** in your file system (within your concrete5 installation). And then make sure that the user can write to that folder that is running PHP in your environment. As explained in the concrete5's own documentation (that you linked originally), it depends on your server which user this is.

Usually in shared hosting environments it's the same as the account you use to login there through SSH or FTP. In these cases, the 755 permissions should be enough if your own user owns the tmp folder you just created.